# Magento configurable product image zoom issue

Tags: jquery, css, magento, prototypejs

I am facing an issue with magento 1.9 theme. I have coustmized this theme according to my requirnments. Every thing is perfect instead of products image zoom. I have developed an extension and the main image is changing according to associate product when we change the value of the dropdown.

But when I hover  over that image it shows the old image. I have added some jquery to adjust the code but no use:

```
  $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jx(document).ready(function(){

      $jx(".midcontent_counter select").change(function(){
             if ($('image-main')){
              var ez = $ja('#image-main').data('elevateZoom');   
              ez.swaptheimage(this.mainImage.src, this.mainImage.src);
        } 
      });

});
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can reset the zoom on change function. or there is any other solution available?

Pl

Comment: Seriously no one? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you gotto change line - syntax error
  Var ez = $ja('#image-main').data('elevateZoom'); to
  Var ez = $jx('#image-main').data('elevateZoom');